# I have issues when I deploy my project with AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, amazon-web-services, passenger

Let me show my Gemfile.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.4.1"

gem 'rails', '5.1.4'
gem 'puma'
gem 'pg'
gem "bower-rails", "~> 0.11.0"
gem 'd3_rails'
# Auth
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'

# Front-end
gem 'react-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'font-awesome-sass'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'jbuilder'

gem 'friendly_id'

# Image upload
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'fog'
gem 'net-ssh'
gem 'sdoc', group: :doc

# Load will_paginate before elasticsearch gems.
gem 'will_paginate'

# Elasticsearch
gem 'elasticsearch-model'
gem 'elasticsearch-rails'

# Background Job
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'sinatra', require: false
gem 'slim'
# gem 'sidetiq', '~> 0.7.0'

gem 'nokogiri'

# Caching
gem 'dalli'
gem 'bundler-audit'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.6'
  gem 'poltergeist'
  gem 'awesome_print'

  gem 'pry-rails'
end

group :development do
  gem 'rails_best_practices'
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'guard-rspec', require: false
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', require: false
  gem 'annotate'
  gem 'bullet'

end

group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'bonsai-elasticsearch-rails'
end
```

There is no error when I install gems, and configured perfectly about Passenger and Apache2 Server. It means when I deploy my rails app, no error.

And I will show apache error.log

```
 N 2017-09-21 12:26:00.3272 883/T5 Ser/Server.h:531 ]: [UstRouterApiServer] Shutdown finished
[ N 2017-09-21 12:26:00.3274 883/T3 Ser/Server.h:531 ]: [UstRouter] Shutdown finished
[ N 2017-09-21 12:26:00.3275 883/T1 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:531 ]: Passenger UstRouter shutdown finished
[ N 2017-09-21 12:26:00.3352 2202/T1 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1283 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ N 2017-09-21 12:26:00.3496 2206/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1083 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ N 2017-09-21 12:26:00.3497 2206/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:248 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ N 2017-09-21 12:26:00.3574 2206/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:830 ]: Passenger core online, PID 2206
[ N 2017-09-21 12:26:00.3742 2212/T1 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:537 ]: Starting Passenger UstRouter...
[ N 2017-09-21 12:26:00.3750 2212/T1 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:350 ]: Passenger UstRouter online, PID 2212
[Thu Sep 21 12:26:00.376239 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 18263:tid 140438528898944] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Phusion_Passenger/5.1.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 21 12:26:00.376261 2017] [core:notice] [pid 18263:tid 140438528898944] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[ N 2017-09-21 12:26:00.5539 877/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1068 ]: Passenger core shutdown finished
[ N 2017-09-21 12:26:02.8255 2206/T8 age/Cor/SecurityUpdateChecker.h:374 ]: Security update check: no update found (next check in 24 hours)
App 2289 stdout: 
App 2289 stdout: BONSAI_URL not present, proceeding with Elasticsearch defaults.
App 2430 stdout:
```

So I test sample rails project because I can't understand why this times out to my proejct on AWS. As a result it works correctly.

I'll show the conf file of the simple project.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName ec2-34-229-186-158.compute-1.amazonaws.com    # Tell Apache and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
   DocumentRoot /var/www/simple/public    
   PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/wrappers/ruby    # Relax Apache security settings
   <Directory /var/www/simple/public>
     Allow from all
     Options -MultiViews
     # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
     Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Only my rails app of deployment doesn't work.

Anyone help me? :)

Answer (score 0):

If a basic app works and your actual app does not that suggests the problem is with your actual app. Does your app take longer than 90 seconds to start? Or does it depend on some configuration which might be missing in your server environment?

You have the 'puma' gem in your gemfile but tagged the question with Passenger. You should only use one or the other.

Comment: It takes about 6 seconds. And then, it shows error page. And I have configured perfectly.